# Проблема с loss

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

В процессе обучения не падает loss. Делаю все это впервые, как я понял, на каждой эпохе loss должен снижаться. Проблема в том, что этого не происходит. Он то снижается, то резкий скачок вверх.
Пробовал менять learning_rate, batch_size, перемешивал наборы данных, результат плюс-минус такой же. Может, не достаточно количества эпох?

```
Training Beginning

Epoch (1/5)
----------------------------------
Test Accuracy : 83.84037929672067  Test Loss : 0.6498197642719652

Epoch (2/5)
----------------------------------
Test Accuracy : 81.58830501777953  Test Loss : 0.6336045114132832

Epoch (3/5)
----------------------------------
Test Accuracy : 78.42749901224812  Test Loss : 0.7707894688222822

Epoch (4/5)
----------------------------------
Test Accuracy : 81.03516396681154  Test Loss : 0.6860072239646762

Epoch (5/5)
----------------------------------
Test Accuracy : 77.79533781114183  Test Loss : 0.7758270732061131

Training Complete
```

Model.py

```
class DeePixBiS(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pretrained=True):
        super().__init__()
        dense = models.densenet161(pretrained=pretrained)
        features = list(dense.features.children())
        self.enc = nn.Sequential(*features[:8])
        self.dec = nn.Conv2d(384, 1, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(14 * 14, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        enc = self.enc(x)
        dec = self.dec(enc)
        out_map = F.sigmoid(dec)
        # print(out_map.shape)
        out = self.linear(out_map.view(-1, 14 * 14))
        out = F.sigmoid(out)
        out = torch.flatten(out)
        return out_map, out
```

Comment: Возможно, модель недостаточно сложная. Покажите конфигурацию нейросети. И что у вас за данные? А может наоборот - модель слишком быстро учится и дальше уже ей нечему учиться. Без деталей непонятно.

Comment: Добавил саму модель, если вы это имели ввиду. Данные - изображения лиц. Разделял на три набора - обучение, валидационный, тестовый (60/20/20)

Comment: Уже лучше. Но вопрос для меня сложный. С таким вам лучше в ods.ai наверное куда-нибудь, тут не факт что ответит кто-то. Я с pretrained моделями не разбирался.

Comment: 1) Пять эпох может быть маловато, попробуйте больше. 2) На предобученной сети вообще может быть мало данных для её смещения (например, предобучили её на миллионе, а у вас всего пятьсот примеров) - сверьте эти количества.

Comment: @Сергей когда обучаю на 2500 изображениях, результат такой, как показан в вопросе. Заметил, что, если обучаю, например, на 100 изображениях, все нормально, loss снижается. Так же пробовал обучать на 30 эпохах (2500 изображений), loss все равно не снижается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вашего ответа на мой вопрос* ясно, что у вас сеть достигает некого предела обучения - у неё малая информационная ёмкость.

Рекомендация: увеличьте число нейронов и число слоёв.

Расскажите потом, как улучшилось.

*Ваш ответ: "обучаю на 2500 изображениях, результат такой, как показан в вопросе. Заметил, что, если обучаю, например, на 100 изображениях, все нормально, loss снижается. Так же пробовал обучать на 30 эпохах (2500 изображений), loss все равно не снижается"

Comment: А правильно ли я понял, что можно просто добавить, например, еще один слой conv2d? Никогда раньше не делал этого

Comment: Заметил еще такую вещь, что на одной базе, вроде, хорошо обучается, а уже на другой иначе, то есть проблема остается, выборки равны при этом

Comment: 1) Можете начать с увеличения окна свёртки. Не поможет - да, добавьте слой. Будет ещё свёртка. Вы ранее никогда в нейронные сети не добавляли слои? 
2) Я просил ранее сверить объёмы данных предобучения и ваших данных для обучения. Какие это количества?

Comment: Получается, я просто добавил еще один слой conv2d. Объемы такие: в первой и второй базе по 2500 для обучения, но в первой loss снижается, во второй нет. Третья база уже моя, там около 100 фотографий, loss снижается стабильно. Только начал изучать нейронки, поэтому могу немного глупые вопросы задавать

Comment: Просьба по пунктам ответить: 1) Т.е. вы говорите, что сеть у вас вообще не предобучена, и вы её обучаете с нуля? 2) При этом на первой базе обучение c нуля идет, на второй базе обучение c нуля не идёт, на третьей обучение c нуля идет? 3) Если да на вопрос 2, это результат после добавления ещё одного слоя или до? 4) Что изменилось после добавления слоя? 5) Окно свёртки пробовали менять? Если да, то что изменилось?

Comment: 1. Я лишь имел ввиду, что неважно, в каком порядке я запускаю обучение для первой и второй баз. Могу сначала первую - вторую, или вторую - первую, для одной из них стабильно loss снижается, для другой нет. 2. Не могу ответить, так как не понимаю, что значит с нуля. 3. Просто добавил еще один слой, взял эти же базы и повторил действия. 4. Не изменилось ничего. 5. Пока добавлял только слой, а как изменить окно свертки, пока не знаю. Это нужно делать в файле model.py?

Comment: 1) Если слой ничего не изменил, то возможно, что вообще архитектура для данного набора данных не подходит. Вам надо тогда читать про свёрточные сети и про то, как подбирать архитектуру, заодно и про окно свёртки прочитаете (предполагаю, что это в `dec` или `linear` в `model.py`, но на этом уровне не работаю с сетью).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136362/discussion-between--and-aleksandr).